# Rails, form WARNING: Can't mass-assign these protected attributes: id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My form is generating a bunch of warnings -  WARNING: Can't mass-assign these protected attributes: id

This is the code I'm using

```
<% MyModel.all.each do |icon| %>
  <%= f.label :attr1, icon.attr1 %>
  <%= f.radio_button :attr1, icon.attr2 %>
<% end %>
```

Note: this isn't happening on the create or update function where I've seen this sort of error before. It is coming from this code here where it generates the radio buttons for the view.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the Model was using an overridden All method which was mass assigning the ID field.  Fixed that and it fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

This become from your Model

In your model you have some attr_accessible or attr_protected field. You need define which field can be updated or not by the mass-assignement in your model.

Comment: I think you didn't read all he said... It is not on the create or update, it is on the generation on the view.

Comment: Interesting. I'm not actually updating anything in this model, I'm just getting options for the radio box from it. 

I'll give your suggestion a go and let you know how I get on. Cheers